# Undefined references when using GCC cross compiler for ARM

Tags: c++, arm, linker-errors, raspberry-pi2

I have been building a GCC cross compiler for ARM using this script
https://gist.github.com/kmhofmann/eea6f7286ddf1b5b3180, so that I can compile programs for a Raspberry Pi 2.

The script itself is heavily based on Jeff Preshing's GCC cross compiler script (see also his blog post http://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/), and I have basically just exchanged a few version numbers (bumped all of them up to the latest versions).

I can come up with a very simple program, however, that already fails to link on my host machine (x86_64, Ubuntu 15.04).

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <future>

int main()
{
    auto getNumber = [](){ return 42; };
    auto f = std::async(getNumber);
    std::cout << "number = " << f.get() << "\n";
}
```

I am building this using CMake/Make, with my CMakeLists.txt looking as follows

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(pitest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}
        -std=c++14 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")

add_executable(pitest main.cpp)

target_compile_options(pitest PRIVATE
    -O2 -ffast-math -mcpu=cortex-a7 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard)
```

and calling

```
CC=~/cross/install/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc \
CXX=~/cross/install/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ \
AR=~/cross/install/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar \
cmake .. && make
```

Instead of a linked executable I get an ugly bunch of linker errors:

```
CMakeFiles/pitest.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `std::__future_base::_Deferred_state<std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()#1} ()>, int>::_M_complete_async()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x264): undefined reference to `std::__atomic_futex_unsigned_base::_M_futex_notify_all(unsigned int*)'
CMakeFiles/pitest.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `std::__future_base::_Deferred_state<std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()#1} ()>, int>::~_Deferred_state()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2e8): undefined reference to `std::__future_base::_Result_base::~_Result_base()'
CMakeFiles/pitest.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()#1} ()>, int>::~_Async_state_impl()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x3a4): undefined reference to `std::__future_base::_Result_base::~_Result_base()'
CMakeFiles/pitest.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::__future_base::_Deferred_state<std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()#1} ()>, int>, std::allocator<std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()#1} ()> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x47c): undefined reference to `std::__future_base::_Result_base::~_Result_base()'
CMakeFiles/pitest.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `std::__future_base::_Deferred_state<std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()#1} ()>, int>::~_Deferred_state()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x528): undefined reference to `std::__future_base::_Result_base::~_Result_base()'
CMakeFiles/pitest.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()#1} ()>, int>, std::allocator<std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()#1} ()> >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x5f0): undefined reference to `std::__future_base::_Result_base::~_Result_base()'
CMakeFiles/pitest.dir/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x6d0): more undefined references to `std::__future_base::_Result_base::~_Result_base()' follow
CMakeFiles/pitest.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::_Bind_simple<main::{lambda()#1} ()>, int>::_Async_state_impl(main::{lambda()#1} (&&)())::{lambda()#1} ()> >::_M_run()':
main.cpp:(.text+0xb8c): undefined reference to `std::__atomic_futex_unsigned_base::_M_futex_notify_all(unsigned int*)'
CMakeFiles/pitest.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `std::__future_base::_Result<int>::~_Result()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt13__future_base7_ResultIiED2Ev[_ZNSt13__future_base7_ResultIiED5Ev]+0x10): undefined reference to `std::__future_base::_Result_base::~_Result_base()'
CMakeFiles/pitest.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `std::__future_base::_Result<int>::~_Result()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt13__future_base7_ResultIiED0Ev[_ZNSt13__future_base7_ResultIiED5Ev]+0x10): undefined reference to `std::__future_base::_Result_base::~_Result_base()'
CMakeFiles/pitest.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `std::__future_base::_Result<int>::_M_destroy()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt13__future_base7_ResultIiE10_M_destroyEv[_ZNSt13__future_base7_ResultIiE10_M_destroyEv]+0x30): undefined reference to `std::__future_base::_Result_base::~_Result_base()'
CMakeFiles/pitest.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr std::make_exception_ptr<std::future_error>(std::future_error)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZSt18make_exception_ptrISt12future_errorENSt15__exception_ptr13exception_ptrET_[_ZSt18make_exception_ptrISt12future_errorENSt15__exception_ptr13exception_ptrET_]+0x58): undefined reference to `std::current_exception()'
CMakeFiles/pitest.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `std::__future_base::_State_baseV2::_M_break_promise(std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter>)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt13__future_base13_State_baseV216_M_break_promiseESt10unique_ptrINS_12_Result_baseENS2_8_DeleterEE[_ZNSt13__future_base13_State_baseV216_M_break_promiseESt10unique_ptrINS_12_Result_baseENS2_8_DeleterEE]+0x120): undefined reference to `std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr::swap(std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr&)'
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt13__future_base13_State_baseV216_M_break_promiseESt10unique_ptrINS_12_Result_baseENS2_8_DeleterEE[_ZNSt13__future_base13_State_baseV216_M_break_promiseESt10unique_ptrINS_12_Result_baseENS2_8_DeleterEE]+0x128): undefined reference to `std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr::~exception_ptr()'
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt13__future_base13_State_baseV216_M_break_promiseESt10unique_ptrINS_12_Result_baseENS2_8_DeleterEE[_ZNSt13__future_base13_State_baseV216_M_break_promiseESt10unique_ptrINS_12_Result_baseENS2_8_DeleterEE]+0x130): undefined reference to `std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr::~exception_ptr()'
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt13__future_base13_State_baseV216_M_break_promiseESt10unique_ptrINS_12_Result_baseENS2_8_DeleterEE[_ZNSt13__future_base13_State_baseV216_M_break_promiseESt10unique_ptrINS_12_Result_baseENS2_8_DeleterEE]+0x178): undefined reference to `std::__atomic_futex_unsigned_base::_M_futex_notify_all(unsigned int*)'
CMakeFiles/pitest.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x50): undefined reference to `std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Result_base()'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x178): undefined reference to `std::__atomic_futex_unsigned_base::_M_futex_wait_until(unsigned int*, unsigned int, bool, std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1ll, 1ll> >, std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000000ll> >)'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1b8): undefined reference to `std::__exception_ptr::operator==(std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr const&, std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr const&)'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1c4): undefined reference to `std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr::~exception_ptr()'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2f4): undefined reference to `std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr::exception_ptr(std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr const&)'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2fc): undefined reference to `std::rethrow_exception(std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr)'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x304): undefined reference to `std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr::~exception_ptr()'
CMakeFiles/pitest.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTINSt13__future_base7_ResultIiEE[_ZTINSt13__future_base7_ResultIiEE]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::__future_base::_Result_base'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/pitest.dir/build.make:85: recipe for target 'pitest' failed
make[2]: *** [pitest] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/pitest.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/pitest.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:76: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

As far as I know, these symbols should be part of libstdc++. Which is compiled together with GCC, which itself is built using the above cross compiler script.

I am already linking libgcc and libstdc++ statically; otherwise I'd run into dynamic symbol loading issues on the target device (since the Raspbian distribution comes with older versions of these.)

The full linker output (before the above errors) is as follows:

```
>>> /home/michael/cross/install/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++  -v  -std=c++14 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++    CMakeFiles/pitest.dir/main.cpp.o  -o pitest -rdynamic
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/home/michael/cross/install/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/michael/cross/install/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../gcc-5.2.0/configure --prefix=/home/michael/cross/install --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-float=hard --disable-multilib --disable-werror
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC) 
COMPILER_PATH=/home/michael/cross/install/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.0/:/home/michael/cross/install/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.0/:/home/michael/cross/install/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/home/michael/cross/install/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.0/:/home/michael/cross/install/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/home/michael/cross/install/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/home/michael/cross/install/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.0/:/home/michael/cross/install/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-std=c++14' '-static-libgcc' '-o' 'pitest' '-rdynamic' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
 /home/michael/cross/install/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.0/collect2 -plugin /home/michael/cross/install/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.0/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/home/michael/cross/install/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.0/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cc4qImrb.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh --eh-frame-hdr -export-dynamic -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 -X -m armelf_linux_eabi -o pitest /home/michael/cross/install/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/crt1.o /home/michael/cross/install/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/crti.o /home/michael/cross/install/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.0/crtbegin.o -L/home/michael/cross/install/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.0 -L/home/michael/cross/install/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib CMakeFiles/pitest.dir/main.cpp.o -Bstatic -lstdc++ -Bdynamic -lm -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lc -lgcc -lgcc_eh /home/michael/cross/install/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.0/crtend.o /home/michael/cross/install/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/crtn.o
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Just to be clear - you can successfully build and run a more basic "hello world" program (ie., `cout << "hello" << endl;`)?  Running a grep over the `nm` output of the library files for strings like `atomic_futex` or `future_base` might give some clues. Also, grepping the header files for the same might also net some results (perhaps support for those things hasn't been ported to ARM yet?).

Comment: Yes, I can build a basic "Hello, world" program (using <iostream>) without issues.

Comment: However, `nm` reveals that the missing symbols are not in any library inside the cross-compiler install directory, so it seems the missing parts have not been built.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Came across exactly the same problem once. The reason is that I try to link my executable(armeabi) against a 3rd party library which is compiled for a different architecture(armeabi-v7a).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this particular problem?

Comment: No, I didn't. Ended up not building the cross compiler in the end.